# sklearn import error - ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.6

I am trying to do this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

and getting an error:

```
In [31]: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-73edc048c06b> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from ._split import BaseCrossValidator
      2 from ._split import KFold
      3 from ._split import GroupKFold
      4 from ._split import StratifiedKFold
      5 from ._split import TimeSeriesSplit

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in <module>()
     29 from ..externals.six import with_metaclass
     30 from ..externals.six.moves import zip
---> 31 from ..utils.fixes import signature, comb
     32 from ..base import _pprint
     33 

ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'
```

any help would be much apreciated.

Comment: Please try re-installing the scikit-learn.

Comment: that indeed did the trick. Thanks Vivek!

Comment: I have the same problem when I run 'from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization'.

Answer (score 20):

SciPy >=0.19 uses `from scipy.special import comb` instead of `from scipy.misc import comb`. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9046

[utils/fixes.py source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/eade48eaa2d7fe5dff669febbad619a244361dd3/sklearn/utils/fixes.py#L36)

```
try:  # SciPy >= 0.19
    from scipy.special import comb, logsumexp
except ImportError:
    from scipy.misc import comb, logsumexp  # noqa
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. conda remove --name your environment --all. Next, re-install the environment. It worked for me.

Comment: It seems that the issue occurs due to a particular package (`scipy`) as @qwr pointed out. So, removing the whole environment would be unnecessary.