# trouble with imports from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have sklearn installed and I can `import sklearn` I can also `import comb`. I `import numpy`, `import scipy`. But when I try:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validation
```

or

```
from sklearn import svm
```

I get a traceback:

```
File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 25, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import comb
ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'
```

Comment: Please add your source code so we can give direct feedback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sklearn import error - ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151453/sklearn-import-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-comb)

Answer (score 1):

Something may have gone wrong in your scipy installation. The issue can be solved by uninstalling and reinstalling the 2 libraries (scipy and sklearn).

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5146)